# Line: -1, Column: -1 System.StringException: Invalid id: '1294888839 ' Apex

Tags: csv, batch-processing, apex

I am trying to read csv from Document object and pass it to a method in apex. The csv only contains account Ids. I am getting an error as
"Line: -1, Column: -1
System.StringException: Invalid id: 'csvid173648'"
Below is my code:

```
String[] filecontent = new String[]{};
Document doc = [Select body from Document where id = 'mydocumentId35661'];
String stringbody = doc.body.tostring();
list<String> filelines = stringbody.split('\n');
System.debug('filelines'+filelines);
Set<Id> accountIdSet = new Set<Id>();
for(Integer i=1; i<filelines.size();i++)
{
    String[] cols = new String[]{};
    cols = filelines[i].split(',');
    System.debug('check cols'+cols);
    accountIdSet.add('\''+ cols[0] + '\'');
}
Map<String,Account_Achievement_Assignment__c> partnerAchievementMap;
partnerAchievementMap = PartnerAchievementHandler.createPartnerAchievementForExistingAccount(accountIdSet,false);
```

I can see the ids are passed correctly in the for loop. Tried to convert string to Id still get the same error. What is the mistake here?